# Database character set Latin for Utf8 Web

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm learning for many hours of encoding,

Indeed I have a database in SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP850_CI_AS

It has characters like Ú, ¶, Þ and others not yet identified. I get strings in UTF-8 for WEB.

I would like to find a solution in PHP to get the right values:

```
Ú > é
¶ > ô
Þ > è
```

I have already done some tests

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding('Ú', 'CP850', 'UTF-8');
```

By placing header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

without success too.
I have the impression that I will have to use a str_replace to solve this problem, I would like to avoid

If you already had this problem?

Comment: 'CP850' is not `Latin1`. Note your `'Ú'` in code may be UTF-8, and so different binary representation than the `'Ú'` you get from files/database, so your example may not work just because you have different data.

Comment: Your issue stems from a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case as follows (example in Python): `'Ú¶Þ'.encode('cp850').decode('latin1')` shows `'éôè'`…